# Setting a provider in widget init is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I'm trying to set a provider variable when a widget gets initialized so that the widget has the appropriate data. I get an error when doing that. Here's the code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      builder: (context) => ListManager(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'crud-to-do',
        home: Home(), // Home calls ListWidget()
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final listManager = Provider.of<ListManager>(context);
      listManager.list = [
        ListItem(title: 'myTtitle', description: 'My desc', id: '1324j323e')
      ];

    if (listManager.list.isEmpty) return Text("hey");
    return Text(listManager.list[0].title);
  }
}
```

This works, but I get an error:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for ListManager:
flutter: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
flutter: This ChangeNotifierProvider<ListManager> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the
flutter: framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be
flutter: built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is
flutter: allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant
flutter: will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
flutter: The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
flutter:   ChangeNotifierProvider<ListManager>
flutter: The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
flutter:   ListWidget
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3680
flutter: #1      Element.markNeedsBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3695
flutter: #2      State.setState
```

So I therefore tried wrapping an `initState` around the setting of `listManager.list` like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  listManager.list = [
        ListItem(title: 'myTtitle', description: 'My desc', id: '1324j323e')
  ];
}
```

But I get an error saying:

> The declaration 'initState' isn't referenced.

What am I doing wrong in both cases, and what's the correct way of setting a `provider`?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your build method, use `Provider.of<ListManager>(context, listen: false)` to prevent a rebuild.

By default, `listen` is set to `true` and will trigger a rebuild when the model changes, which will throw an exception in a `build()` method or an `initState()`.

Comment: Same here.  I following the advice given here and am still getting an error.